# Does PowerShell support constants?

Tags: powershell, constants

I would like to declare some integer constants in PowerShell.

Is there any good way to do that?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Use

```
Set-Variable test -Option Constant -Value 100
```

or

```
Set-Variable test -Option ReadOnly -Value 100
```

The difference between "Constant" and "ReadOnly" is that a read-only variable can be removed (and then re-created) via

```
Remove-Variable test -Force
```

whereas a constant variable can't be removed (even with -Force).

See [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347562.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Hmm, but **how do you force the datatype** when using `Set-Variable`? When dealing with variables one may use `[string]$name = value` but that seems not to be possible for constants?

Comment: @masi just force the value `Set-Variable test -option Constant -value [string]100`

Comment: @Monso You need parentheses around the value when specifying type like `([string]100)`. See answers below.

Comment: This doesn't create a constant.   As the variable cannot be used in validation sets.

  [ValidateSet($RunTypeStandard ,"Debug" ,"DebugWithEnvironment" )]

I still get the error that "Attribute argument needs to be a constant"

Comment: Another difference between `-Option Constant` and `-Option ReadOnly` is, that you can apply `ReadOnly` to an existing variable, e. g. `$CONST_FOO = 42; $CONST_BAR = 23; Set-Variable CONST_* -Option ReadOnly`. I'm now using this scheme because it works better with code navigation. E. g. VSCode's PowerShell extension is able to navigate to the definition of a variable only if it is defined regularly (`$var = value`). By using a common prefix I only need to call `Set-Variable` once, which makes the code cleaner.

Answer (score 22):

Here is a solution for defining a constant like this:

```
const myConst = 42
```

Solution taken from http://poshcode.org/4063

```
    function Set-Constant {
  <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Creates constants.
    .DESCRIPTION
        This function can help you to create constants so easy as it possible.
        It works as keyword 'const' as such as in C#.
    .EXAMPLE
        PS C:\> Set-Constant a = 10
        PS C:\> $a += 13

        There is a integer constant declaration, so the second line return
        error.
    .EXAMPLE
        PS C:\> const str = "this is a constant string"

        You also can use word 'const' for constant declaration. There is a
        string constant named '$str' in this example.
    .LINK
        Set-Variable
        About_Functions_Advanced_Parameters
  #>
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$Name,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
    [char][ValidateSet("=")]$Link,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
    [object][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$Mean,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$Surround = "script"
  )

  Set-Variable -n $name -val $mean -opt Constant -s $surround
}

Set-Alias const Set-Constant
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when `Set-Constant` is contained in a module. It will create a constant in the module scope, where `Set-Constant` is contained. As a workaround one could pass parameter `-Surround Global`, but that's not always wanted. I would like to create a constant in another module or locally in a function.

Answer (score 16):

To use a specific type of value, say Int64, you can explicitly cast the value used in set-variable.

For instance:

```
set-variable -name test -value ([int64]100) -option Constant
```

To check,

```
$test | gm
```

And you'll see that it is an Int64 (rather than Int32, which would be normal for the value 100).

Comment: This could be shortened to: `set -o const test ([int64]100)`. This is one of the few cases where I would prefer the alias over the full command name in a script, to let my mind "scan" the source code quicker.

Comment: I don't agree.  `set -o` is a bit too cryptic for me to have in a script.

Answer (score 14):

I really like the syntactic sugar that [rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17839741/7571258) provides:

```
const myConst = 42
```

Unfortunately his solution doesn't work as expected when you define the `Set-Constant` function in a **module**. When called from outside the module, it will create a constant in the module scope, where `Set-Constant` is defined, instead of the **caller's scope**. This makes the constant invisible to the caller.

The following modified function fixes this problem. The solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718967/7571258) to the question ["Is there any way for a powershell module to get at its caller's scope?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528262/is-there-any-way-for-a-powershell-module-to-get-at-its-callers-scope/46718967#46718967).

```sh
$null = New-Module {
    function Set-Constant {
        <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Creates constants.
        .DESCRIPTION
            This function can help you to create constants so easy as it possible.
            It works as keyword 'const' as such as in C#.
        .EXAMPLE
            PS C:\> Set-Constant a = 10
            PS C:\> $a += 13

            There is a integer constant declaration, so the second line return
            error.
        .EXAMPLE
            PS C:\> const str = "this is a constant string"

            You also can use word 'const' for constant declaration. There is a
            string constant named '$str' in this example.
        .LINK
            Set-Variable
            About_Functions_Advanced_Parameters
        #>
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)] [string] $Name,
            [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=1)] [char] [ValidateSet('=')] $Link,
            [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=2)] [object] $Value
        )

        try {
            $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Set( 
                [Management.Automation.PSVariable]::new( 
                    $Name, $Value, [Management.Automation.ScopedItemOptions]::Constant ) )
        }
        catch {
            # This makes sure the location of the call to Set-Constant is reported 
            # in the error message, instead of the location of the call to PSVariable.Set().
            $PSCmdlet.WriteError( $_ )
        }
    }
}

Set-Alias const Set-Constant
```

**Notes:**

- The `New-Module` line is there because the function **only** works, when called from a different *scope domain* (aka *session state*). You could put the function into an actual module file (.psm1), but then you couldn't use it from within that same module! The in-memory module makes it usable as-is from both PowerShell scripts (.ps1) as well as module files.
- I've renamed the parameter `-Mean` to `-Value`, for consistency with `Set-Variable`.
- The function could be extended to optionally set the `Private`, `ReadOnly` and `AllScope` flags. Simply add the desired values to the 3rd argument of the [`PSVariable` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psvariable.-ctor?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_PSVariable__ctor_System_String_System_Object_System_Management_Automation_ScopedItemOptions_), which is called in the above script through `New-Object`.

---

**Edit 06/2023:**

A disadvantage of both `Set-Constant` and any solution based on `Set-Variable -Option Constant` is, that **VSCode's PowerShell extension does not support navigation** to the definition of the variable, e. g. by <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> on the variable name (see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/379)).

My current **workaround** is to define the constants like normal variables (so VSCode sees their definition in the AST) and then make them constant by redefining them using `New-Variable -Force -Option Constant`. Contrary to `Set-Variable`, the `New-Variable` command can overwrite existing variables.

A typical module that exports constants, now looks like this:

```bash
# Define variables
$CONST_FOO = 42
$CONST_BAR = 23

# Make the variables constant, by redefining them as constants.
Get-Variable CONST_* | ForEach-Object { New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value -Option Constant -Force }

# Export the constants from the module
Export-ModuleMember -Variable CONST_*
```

Here is a full demo to play around with:

```bash
$null = New-Module {
    $CONST_FOO = 42
    $CONST_BAR = 23
    
    Get-Variable CONST_* | ForEach-Object { New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value -Option Constant -Force }
    Export-ModuleMember -Variable CONST_*
}

# All of these should error out
$CONST_FOO = 0
$CONST_BAR = 0
Remove-Variable CONST_FOO -Force
```

Comment: You could check the call stack to find out where the assignment took place:
`if ((Get-PSCallStack)[1].Command -eq 'your-module-file-name.psm1') { <# inside module #> } else { <# outside #> }`

Comment: @pfeileon Found a different way using an in-memory module.

Answer (score 13):

Use `-option Constant` with the `Set-Variable` cmdlet:

```
Set-Variable myvar -option Constant -value 100
```

Now `$myvar` has a constant value of 100 and cannot be modified.

Comment: Wow, that's clunky. You have to use Set-Variable to do it, huh?

Comment: Yes, there's not unclunky way to do it :)

Comment: you can also modify and existing variable with either set-variable (aliased to sv) or by using get-variable (gv) and tinkering with its Options property.

Comment: Hmm, but how do you force the datatype when using `Set-Variable`? When dealing with variables one may use `[string]$name = value` but that seems not to be possible for constants?

Comment: @masi - see Mike Shepard's answer elsewhere in this page. Copy and pasting from there, it's: `set-variable -name test -value ([int64]100) -option Constant`

Answer (score 2):

There is really 0 benefit from creating a constant thru a [`psvariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psvariable?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0). There is no performance gain and it can be updated via reflection at will:

```bash
$var = Set-Variable notareal -Value constant -Option Constant -PassThru
$var.GetType().GetField('_value', 'NonPublic, Instance').SetValue($var, 'nope')
$notareal
```

It's not a real constant. If you want a real `const` the way is thru inline C#:

```
$addTypeSplat = @{
    MemberDefinition = 'public const string Const = "myConstValue";'
    Name             = 'MyConstClass'
    Namespace        = 'MyNamespace'
}

Add-Type @addTypeSplat
[MyNamespace.MyConstClass]::Const
```

Or the closest you can get to it from PowerShell is with a `static` property in a PowerShell Class (from a performance standpoint):

```
class MyConst {
    static [string] $Const = 'constValue'
}
```

Answer (score -7):

PowerShell v5.0 should allow

[static] [int] $variable = 42

[static] [DateTime] $thisday

and the like.

Comment: does not work on ps 5.1. Unable to find type [static].

Comment: Not to mention, static is not the same as a constant