# Is there any way for a powershell module to get at its caller's scope?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have a collection of utility functions and other code that I dot-source into every powershell file I write. Having gotten bit by caller scope variables influencing it, I started looking into changing it into a powershell module.

I ran into problems with a couple of the special things I do in it where I actually do want some interaction between the scopes. I'm wondering if there is anyway to "get at" the scope of a module's caller to keep this functionality while moving to a powershell module?

If not, is my best path forward to keep these more specialized things in a dot-sourced file and move the more traditional utility functions into a module? Here are the things that don't easily move to a module:

- Setting strict mode and error action preferences to keep sane, e.g.:

  ```
  Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
  $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
  $PSDefaultParameterValues['*:ErrorAction']='Stop'
  ```

  This (as expected) has no effect on the caller's environment when the code is run from a .psm1 powershell module. Is there any way to cross from the psm1 scope to the caller scope to make these changes?
- Printing out information about the top-level script call, e.g.:

  ```
  $immediateCallerPath = Get-Variable -scope 1 -name PSCommandPath -ValueOnly
  Write-Host "Starting script at $immediateCallerPath"
  $boundParameters = Get-Variable -scope 1 -name PSBoundParameters -ValueOnly
  Write-Host "Bound parameters are:"
  foreach($psbp in $boundParameters.GetEnumerator())
  {
          "({0},{1})" -f $psbp.Key,$psbp.Value | Write-Host
  }
  ```

  Likewise, these commands can no longer see the top-most calling scope once placed in a .psm1 file

Answer (score 8):

`$PSCmdlet.SessionState` seems to provide a function inside a script module access to the call site's variables provided the call site is outside the module.  (If the call site is inside the module, you can just use `Get-` and `Set-Variable -Scope`.)  Here is an example using `SessionState`:

```
New-Module {
    function Get-CallerVariable {
        param([Parameter(Position=1)][string]$Name)
        $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue($Name)
    }
    function Set-CallerVariable {
        param(
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)][string]$Value,
            [Parameter(Position=1)]$Name
        )
        process { $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Set($Name,$Value)}
    }
} | Import-Module

$l = 'original value'
Get-CallerVariable l
'new value' | Set-CallerVariable l
$l
```

which outputs

```
original value
new value
```

I'm not sure whether `SessionState` was intended to be used in this manner.  For what it's worth, this is the same technique used in [`Get-CallerPreference.ps1`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Inherit-Preference-82343b9d).  There are also some test cases [here](https://github.com/alx9r/ToolFoundations/blob/a71933b7a73cb1be119310e746636b1af4515d36/EnvironmentTests/callerScope.Tests.ps1) which pass on PowerShell versions 2 through 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand completely what you are after. I believe you would like to know where is the code implemented that invokes the cmdlets of you module. Maybe even further up.

If I'm correct then you can use `Get-PSCallStack` to retrieve the stack trace. For example from an unsaved script it looks like this

```
PS C:\Users\asarafian> Get-PSCallStack

Command       Arguments Location 
-------       --------- -------- 
<ScriptBlock> {}        <No file>
```

If the file was saved then it would look like this

```
PS C:\Users\asarafian> Get-PSCallStack

Command       Arguments Location 
-------       --------- -------- 
File1.ps1           <No file>
```

Depending on what you want to achieve, which is not clear to me, you need to walk the list from `[0]` which is the code that executed `Get-PSCallStack` to `[x]`.

When building the [XWrite](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/XWrite) I wanted also to figure out if an entry from the stack was a script file, a cmdlet part of a module or unknown like `<ScriptBlock>`.

My implementation is in [Get-XCommandSource.ps1](https://github.com/Sarafian/XWrite/blob/master/Source/Modules/XWrite/Private/Get-XCommandSource.ps1) and it follows the following logic for the command value from the stacktrace

1. if it ends with `.ps1` then it's a script file.
2. if it is `<ScriptBlock>` then it's a script block.
3. if the command can be loaded with `Get-Command` then

   1. if it has a module then it's a cmdlet in a module.
   2. if not then it's a cmdlet/function imported with `.\cmdlet.ps1` pattern.

Here is the implementation:

```
function Get-XCommandSource
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [AllowNull()]
        [string]$Command
    )
    begin {

    }

    process {
        if(-not $Command)
        {
            "Unknown"
        }
        elseif($Command.EndsWith(".ps1"))
        {
            "Script"
        }
        elseif($Command -eq "<scriptblock>")
        {
            "Unknown"
        }
        else
        {
            $cmdlet=Get-Command -Name $command -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if($cmdlet)
            {
                $moduleName=$cmdlet|Select-Object -ExpandProperty ModuleName

                if($moduleName)
                {
                    $moduleName
                }
                else
                {
                    "Function"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                "Unknown"
            }
        }
    }

    end {

    }
}
```