# What is the difference between a cmdlet and a function?

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

There are two elements in a [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest?view=powershell-7.3): cmdlet and function.

What is the difference between a cmdlet and a function?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A cmdlet is a .NET class written in C# or other .NET language and contained in a .dll (i.e. in a binary module). A function is specified directly in PowerShell in a script, script module or at the command line. A module manifest may include both script and binary modules so the manifest needs to be able to export both cmdlets and functions. It's even possible to have both a cmdlet and a function with the same name exported from a single manifest though that's generally not recommended.

Comment: It’s worth also highlighting that many community modules provide cmdlets that are written as functions but that behave (from a user perspective) exactly like an actual cmdlet described above.

Comment: Note that the PowerShell team has officially changed the definition of the word cmdlet to include "advanced functions" and the like. See https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6105

Answer (score 42):

To complement [Bruce Payette's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911452/45375):

Not all functions are created equal in PowerShell:

- An [***advanced* function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced) is the written-in-PowerShell **analog of a (binary) *cmdlet*** (which, as stated, is *compiled* from a .NET language); decorating a function's `param(...)` block with the [`[CmdletBinding()]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute) or decorating at least one [parameter with a `[Parameter()]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) <sup>thanks, [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers)</sup>
  is what makes it an *advanced* one; as such, it supports certain **standard behaviors**:

  - You gain automatic support for [*common parameters*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) such as `-Verbose`, and `-OutVariable` and, on an opt-in basis, for `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm`.
  - Arguments that cannot be bound to explicitly declared parameters result in an error on invocation.
  - Typically, but not necessarily, advanced functions support one-by-one pipeline-input processing via a `process { ... }` script block, via parameter-binding parameters decorated with `ValueFromPipeline` and/or `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`.
  - Unfortunately, even **advanced functions and cmdlets aren't created fully equal**:

    - Advanced functions run in a *child variable scope*, unlike cmdlets.

      - However, it is possible to gain access to the caller's variables even in functions placed in *modules* (to functions outside of modules the caller's variables are visible by default, owing to PowerShell's dynamic scoping), via the `$PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable` object, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718967/45375).
    - Advanced functions [apply *culture-invariant* parameter conversions, unlike cmdlets](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989).
    - Advanced functions, in *Windows PowerShell*, [handle `ValueFromRemainingArguments` differently than cmdlets](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2035).

      - This inconsistency was resolved in PowerShell *Core*, but, unfortunately, in a manner that created more problems than it solved - see GitHub issues [#5955](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5955) and [#6451](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6451).
- A [***simple* function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions), by contrast:

  - is **appropriate for script- and module-internal *helper* functions**
  - requires less "ceremony" (simpler syntax without parameter attributes, single-script-block body)

    - Note: Unlike advanced functions and cmdlets, simple functions accept *arbitrary arguments*, whether they bind to declared parameters or not; unbound ones are reflected in the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71429321/45375) for how to *prevent* passing unbound (unexpected) arguments.
  - can, however, still process pipeline input via automatic variable `$Input` or even via a `process { ... }` block, if desired.
  - also runs in a *child scope* by default; outside of modules (which simple function shouldn't be exported from anyway), the caller's variables are *visible* owing to PowerShell's dynamic scoping; *modifying* them (which should generally be avoided) requires calls to `Set-Variable` with `-Scope 1`.
  - Note that there's also a specialized, but rarely used *variant* of a simple function optimized for pipeline processing, defined with the `Filter` keyword. Its body is implicitly invoked for each pipeline input object, reflected in automatic variable `$_`.

While **exporting functions as part of a module** - preferably via its module manifest (`*.psd1`) - doesn't *enforce* that functions are *advanced* ones, it is **good practice to only export *advanced* functions**.

Comment: I know it's a different question, but I wanted to ask it here: is there a difference in the name of the [functions for which `SupportsShouldProcess=$true` and `SupportsShouldProcess=$false`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute)

Comment: @mazzy: No, there are no specific names for these sub-types of advanced functions, but those that do implement `SupportsShouldProcess` gain support for the `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm` common parameters.

Comment: _"Advanced functions run in a child variable scope, unlike cmdlets"_ -- True, but there is [a way to access variables in the parent (caller's) scope through `$PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718967/7571258).