# ErrorActionPreference behaving differently as ErrorAction parameter

Tags: powershell

I have the following code in PowerShell 5.1

```
$ErrorActionPreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Stop
...
  
try {
    $scopes = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $dhcphost -CimSession $dhcphostx
    ...
} catch {
    Write-Warning "Failed to query local DHCP server! Server 2003 system?"
}
```

Some of the DHCP servers which the script will query are Server 2003 and on those servers, the code will fail. If the error is the following, the try...cath will get triggered and my warning will get displayed as expected

```
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (PS_DhcpServerv4Scope:String) [Get-DhcpServerv4Scope], CimJobExcept     ion                                                                                                                              
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CimJob_BrokenCimSession,Get-DhcpServerv4Scope                                                 
+ PSComputerName        : S1773C01
```

But on the following error, the try...catch will not trigger

```
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PS_DhcpServerv4Scope:root/Microsoft/...cpServerv4Scope) [Get-DhcpServerv4Scope], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80338000,Get-DhcpServerv4Scope
+ PSComputerName        : S1761C01
```

The try...catch will ONLY trigger on both errors when setting the ErrorAction parameter

```
$scopes = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $dhcphost -CimSession $dhcphostx -ErrorAction Stop
```

So ErrorActionPreference does not always throw and gets overridden by ErrorAction parameter in this case. Why is this happening and is there a way to have the global ErrorActionPreference ALWAYS throw an error?

Comment: If I remember well try only triggers on terminating errors. Seems that Get-DhcpServerv4Scope isn't one if not explicitly requested with -errorAction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The **[`Get-DhcpServerv4Scope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/get-dhcpserverv4scope?view=windowsserver2019-ps) cmdlet (all cmdlets that come with the `DhcpServer` module) is implemented as an ([advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)) *function***<sup>[1]</sup> (PowerShell code) rather than via a *binary* (as a class from a compiled .NET assembly, originally typically written in C#).

  - To verify, inspect the output from
    `(Get-Command Get-DhcpServerv4Scope).CommandType`
- Regrettably, these two implementation methods result in *different behavior*, and you're seeing one aspect of it:

  - **A (cmdlet-like advanced) function defined in a *module* does *not* see the caller's variables, which includes [*preference* variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables) such as `$ErrorActionPreference`** (except when calling directly from the *global* scope).

    - Therefore, such **preference variables aren't honored**. See [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568) for a discussion of this problematic behavior.
    - By contrast, [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters) such as `-ErrorAction` *are* processed correctly.
  - Additional behavioral differences exist, independently of whether a given advanced function is defined in a module or not - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51912471/45375).

---

**Workaround**:

- Complement `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` with a local copy of [`$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psdefaultparametervalues) that *presets* use of `-ErrorAction Stop`  when calling cmdlets (from the caller's scope and its descendant scopes):

  ```
  # Still necessary so as to also terminate on *expression*
  # errors, such as exceptions thrown by .NET calls.
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'    

  # Create a local copy of $PSDefaultParameterValues; without it,
  # changes would take effect session-globally.
  # To start with a clean slate, call .Clear() afterwards.
  $PSDefaultParameterValues = $PSDefaultParameterValues.Clone()

  # Preset -ErrorAction Stop for all cmdlet calls, which is 
  # also effective for cmdlets implemented as advanced functions
  # in modules.
  $PSDefaultParameterValues['*:ErrorAction'] = 'Stop'
  ```

Note: Conceivably, you could use `$global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` to set the *global* instance of the preference variable, which functions in modules *do* see. However, this requires saving the original global value and restoring it in a `finally` script block of a [`try / catch / finally` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) that encloses your entire code, so that future code executed in the same session isn't affected.

---

<sup>[1] More specifically, the module's functions are implemented as CIM wrappers via [CDXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/cdxml-overview).</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @biepbiep; my pleasure.