# Perform functions default action, unless pipeline input was given?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, default-value

Lets say I have a function like this:

```
Function Hello(){
    Write-Host "Hello, World"}
```

when used on its own it works perfect but I would also like for it to receive pipeline input:

```
$MyString = "Something Else please"
$MyString | Hello
```

In the second example, `Something Else please` should be printed instead of the default value of `Hello, World`.

I have searched and searched and have turned up empty handed. everything out there keeps mentioning default parameters. I am not looking to use parameters.

Someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can use `$MyInvocation.ExpectingInput` to see if the function will receive input from pipeline

Comment: Hey thats exactly what I needed, I did more searching and testing and I got it working, thanks allot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[*Declare a parameter*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters)**, and:

- assign it a  *default value*.
- make it *pipeline-binding*, and be sure to process *each* pipeline input object in the function body, namely via a `process` block

  - Note: Declaring a parameter pipeline-binding (with `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]` below) implicitly makes a function an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one, which has (generally beneficial) behavioral implications - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51912471/45375).

```bash
function Hello {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject = 'Hello, World'   # default value
  )
  
  process {
    # Called for each pipeline input object, or once with the default value.
    Write-Host $InputObject
  }

}
```

For robustness, it's **generally preferable to declare parameters *explicitly***, as shown above.

---

The - less desirable - ***parameter-less*, *simple*-function alternative** is the following, which **collects all pipeline input *up front***, as it too implicitly runs in an `end` block, and uses the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) and  **`$MyInvocation.ExpectingInput` to detect if pipeline input was provided**, as suggested by [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon):

```bash
function Hello {

  if ($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { # input from the pipeline
    $input | Write-Host  # pass each pipeline input object to Write-Host
  } else { # no pipeline input -> use default value
    'Hello, World' | Write-Host
  }

}
```

---

As for **what you tried** in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74339834/45375):

- By not using a `process` block, in effect only the *last* input object from the pipeline is bound to parameter `$InputObject`, because a function body without (any one of) `begin`, `process` and `end` blocks implicitly runs in an `end` block, i.e. *after* all pipeline input has been received.
- Generally, there's no good reason to type a parameter `[PSObject]` or `[PSObject[]]`, given that [`[psobject]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSObject) is a usually invisible *helper* type used *behind the scenes*.

  - *Not* typing a parameter is the same as typing it `[object]`, which is what should be used to accept arguments of any type.
  - Typing it `[array]` is the same as typing it `[object[]]`, but note that if you type a pipeline-binding parameter as an *array*, each individual input object is automatically *converted to an array* - which slows down processing.

    - Only if you need to accept multiple values *as a single command-line argument* (as opposed to via the pipeline) is declaring a parameter as an array warranted - and when you do, you then need to *enumerate* each bound parameter value in your `process` block, as it may itself be a true array.
    - As an aside: That pipeline-binding parameters declared with scalar types only accept multiple values *via the pipeline*, but not also implicitly *as an argument* is the subject of [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242)

Answer (score 3):

By using this syntax for you function you can create what I think you're after.

```
Clear-Host

Function Hello {

  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
      [String] $MyText = "Hello"
  )
    Write-Host "$MyText, World"
}

Hello

"It's A Wonderful" | Hello
```

Output:

```
Hello, World
It's A Wonderful, World
PS>
```

Comment: I tested this and it seems to execute both "conditions" simoultaneously. I was looking for an `If` or `Else` like solution. Thanks for the example though, much appreciated.

Comment: That's only because I called the function twice to demonstrate both call methods. The function will only execute either the default or the passed string when called.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I arrived at after @Santiago Squarzon pointed me to the right direction

```
Function Hello {
    Param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
      [PSObject[]] $InputObject,
    )
    if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) {
        "Data received from pipeline input: '$($InputObject)'"
    }
 
    else {
        Write-host "Hello World"
    }
  }
```

Comment: You would need to include a `process` block in your function otherwise it would only process the last element coming from the pipeline. Aside from that looks good 