# Powershell : Function to create new-variable not working

Tags: function, powershell, variables

I'm trying to make a simple function to create Variables in powershell with generated name

I'm using this code :

```
    function createAnewVariable {
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
          [String]$Name
    )
    New-Variable -Name GenLink$Name -Value "AMIGA" -Option AllScope
}

createAnewVariable -Name "AutoVAR"
```

Outside a function it's working perfectly when i do a get-variable i can see my automatic created variables like $GenLinkName
but inside a function i don't have access to the varaible in the list and i can't call it !
oO

It's maybe simple but i don't understand why :)

Someone can tell me where i'm wrong please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables in PowerShell [are *scoped*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes), and defaults to the current local scope, ie. the function body. The `AllScope` option does not make it available to antecedent scopes, it simply ensures PowerShell *copies* the variable into any new child scope created from the current scope.

To make the variable available in the parent scope, use `-Scope 1` when calling `New-Variable`:

```
function createAnewVariable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [String]$Name
    )
    
    New-Variable -Name "GenLink$Name" -Value "AMIGA" -Scope 1
}

createAnewVariable -Name "AutoVAR"

# This is now available in the calling scope
$GenLinkAutoVAR
```

Be aware that if the *function* is module-scoped (eg. the function is part of a module), the parent scope will be the module scope, meaning all other functions in the same module will be able to see it too.

Comment: From module scope one can use `$PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Set()` to [set a variable in the caller's scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718967/7571258).