# Access a variable from parent scope

Tags: powershell

In Single Module Scenario: Running Set-Var returns 10.

```
# m.psm1

function Set-Var {
    $MyVar = 10
    Get-Var
}

function Get-Var {
    $MyVar
}
```

In Nested Modules Scenario: Running Set-Var does not return any value.

```
# m1.psm1

function Get-Var {
    $MyVar
}
```

```
# m.psm1

Import-Module .\m1.psm1

function Set-Var {
    $MyVar = 10
    Get-Var
}
```

How do I achieve the same effect as a single module with nested modules? Using `$script:MyVar` also does not work. However, I would like to keep the scope of the variable local to enable concurrent executions with different values.

Comment: I guess then you should be using parameters to the functions, otherwise $MyVar is just a local variable ($null) inside each of the functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because local variables are not inherited by functions in nested module context.

You can do this instead:

```sh
$null = New-Module {
    function Get-Var {
        [CmdletBinding()] param()
        $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Get('MyVar').Value
    }
}
```

- The `New-Module` command creates an in-memory module, because this code only works when the caller is in a *different module or script*.
- Use the `CmdletBinding` attribute to create an [advanced function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2). This is a prerequisite to use the automatic `$PSCmdlet` variable, which we need in the next step.
- Use its `SessionState.PSVariable` member to get or set a variable from the parent (module) scope.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54314996/7571258) shows an example how to *set* a variable in the parent (module) scope.
- See also: [Is there any way for a powershell module to get at its caller's scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46528262/7571258)

Comment: Tested this out. It gets the variable from the immediate parent. Since, we get access to the parent's PSCmdlet also, we can keep moving to the previous caller. Is there a way to do the same if the caller is in the same module? I saw your other post with Get-Variable -scope 1. Any way to do that in C# directly without an invocation?

Comment: @NavaneethP What do you mean by "Any way to do that in C# directly without an invocation?". Do you mean a compiled cmdlet written in C#?

Comment: Yes. Compiled cmdlet written in C#. GetVariableValue and SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue don't have a scope parameter.

Comment: @NavaneethP Sorry, can't help with that. I've never written compiled cmdlet.